# JS Calculator does not calculate correct variables

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a calculator but I have the following problem:

When I type 5 + 3 = .... I get 8. That works.
However when I type - 2 = .... I get 1.
The problem happenes in the dataOperators and especially in the code "disNum2 = disNum1;"

The first time I run dataOperators.forEach the calcultae works correct.
Then I hit the equal sign and the result is correct.
After the result is calculated I press another operator followed by a number.
Then I press the equal sign again and now the variable disNum2 contains disNum1 instead of the result.

I hope that you could give me some advice.

Thanks in advance!

```js
const myInput = document.querySelector('#result');
const myOperator = document.querySelector('#operator');
const dataNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.dataNumber');
const dataOperators = document.querySelectorAll('.dataOperator');
const dataEquals = document.querySelector('.dataEquals');
const dataClear = document.querySelector('.dataClear');

let disNum1 = ''; 
let disNum2 = ''; 
let result = '';
let hasDot = false;
let hasZero = false;
let lastOperation = '';

dataNumbers.forEach((number) => {
    number.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
        const clickedNum = e.target.innerText;
        if (clickedNum === '.' && !hasDot) {
            hasDot = true;
        } else if (clickedNum === '.' && hasDot) {
            return;
        }
        
        if (clickedNum === '.' && !hasZero) {
            hasZero = true;
        } else if (clickedNum === '.' && hasZero) {
            return;
        }
        
        disNum1 += clickedNum;
        myInput.value = disNum1;
    })
})

dataOperators.forEach((operation) => {
    operation.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        hasDot = false;
        hasZero = false;
        const clickedOp = e.target.innerText
        lastOperation = clickedOp;
        myOperator.value = clickedOp;
        disNum2 = disNum1;
        disNum1 = '';
   })
})

function mathOperation() {
    if (lastOperation === 'x') {
        result = parseFloat(disNum2) * parseFloat(disNum1);
    } else if (lastOperation === "+") {
        result = parseFloat(disNum2) + parseFloat(disNum1);
    } else if (lastOperation === "-") {
        result = parseFloat(disNum2) - parseFloat(disNum1);
    } else if (lastOperation === "/") {
        result = parseFloat(disNum2) / parseFloat(disNum1);
    } else if (lastOperation === "%") {
        result = parseFloat(disNum2) % parseFloat(disNum1);
    }
}

dataEquals.addEventListener("click", () => {
    hasDot = false;
    hasZero = false;
    mathOperation();
    myInput.value = result; 
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#calculator {
    width: 500px;
}

#keys {
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

#numbers {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 75%;
    justify-content: center;
}

#operators {
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

#numbers div,
#operators div {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
}

#numbers div {
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

#numbers div:active,
#operators div:active {

    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
}

#screen {
    margin: 18px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
    background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3);
    display: flex;

}

#result,
#operator {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 42px;
    text-align: right;
    border: none;
}

#operator {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="calculator">
        <div id="screen">
            <input type="text" id="result" placeholder="0" value="" disabled>
            <input type="text" id="operator" disabled>
        </div>
        <div id="keys">
            <div id="numbers">
                <div class="dataNumber">7</div>
                <div class="dataNumber">8</div>
                <div class="dataNumber">9</div>
                <div class="dataNumber">4</div>
                <div class="dataNumber">5</div>
                <div class="dataNumber">6</div>
                <div class="dataNumber">1</div>
                <div class="dataNumber">2</div>
                <div class="dataNumber">3</div>
                <div class="dataNumber">.</div>
                <div class="dataNumber">0</div>
                <div class="dataEquals">=</div>
            </div>
            <div id="operators">
                <div class="dataClear">C</div>
                <div class="dataOperator">+</div>
                <div class="dataOperator">-</div>
                <div class="dataOperator">x</div>
                <div class="dataOperator">/</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The HTML section of the snippet editor should only contain the content of the `<body>` tag -> [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: _"Then I press the equal sign again and now the variable disNum2 contains disNum1 instead of the result."_ - you did `disNum2 = disNum1; disNum1 = '';` when the operator was clicked. And now in your calculation, when the operator was `-`, you do `parseFloat(disNum2) - parseFloat(disNum1)` - so that is basically disNum1 minus 0 now.

Comment: You need to handle the case that your first operand wasn't actually _entered_, but is the result of a previous operation, properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate the result, you probably just need to copy the result into `disNum2`, see the last line of the JS:

```js
const myInput = document.querySelector('#result');
const myOperator = document.querySelector('#operator');
const dataNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.dataNumber');
const dataOperators = document.querySelectorAll('.dataOperator');
const dataEquals = document.querySelector('.dataEquals');
const dataClear = document.querySelector('.dataClear');

let disNum1 = ''; 
let disNum2 = ''; 
let result = '';
let hasDot = false;
let hasZero = false;
let lastOperation = '';

dataNumbers.forEach((number) => {
    number.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
        const clickedNum = e.target.innerText;
        if (clickedNum === '.' && !hasDot) {
            hasDot = true;
        } else if (clickedNum === '.' && hasDot) {
            return;
        }
        
        if (clickedNum === '.' && !hasZero) {
            hasZero = true;
        } else if (clickedNum === '.' && hasZero) {
            return;
        }
        
        disNum1 += clickedNum;
        myInput.value = disNum1;
    })
})

dataOperators.forEach((operation) => {
    operation.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        hasDot = false;
        hasZero = false;
        const clickedOp = e.target.innerText
        lastOperation = clickedOp;
        myOperator.value = clickedOp;
        disNum2 = disNum1;
        disNum1 = '';
   })
})

function mathOperation() {
    if (lastOperation === 'x') {
        result = parseFloat(disNum2) * parseFloat(disNum1);
    } else if (lastOperation === "+") {
        result = parseFloat(disNum2) + parseFloat(disNum1);
    } else if (lastOperation === "-") {
        result = parseFloat(disNum2) - parseFloat(disNum1);
    } else if (lastOperation === "/") {
        result = parseFloat(disNum2) / parseFloat(disNum1);
    } else if (lastOperation === "%") {
        result = parseFloat(disNum2) % parseFloat(disNum1);
    }
}

dataEquals.addEventListener("click", () => {
    hasDot = false;
    hasZero = false;
    mathOperation();
    myInput.value = result;
    disNum2 = result; // Your result is now also the 2nd number.
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#calculator {
    width: 500px;
}

#keys {
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

#numbers {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 75%;
    justify-content: center;
}

#operators {
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

#numbers div,
#operators div {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
}

#numbers div {
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

#numbers div:active,
#operators div:active {

    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
}

#screen {
    margin: 18px;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
    background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3);
    display: flex;

}

#result,
#operator {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 42px;
    text-align: right;
    border: none;
}

#operator {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
    <div id="screen">
        <input type="text" id="result" placeholder="0" value="" disabled>
        <input type="text" id="operator" disabled>
    </div>
    <div id="keys">
        <div id="numbers">
            <div class="dataNumber">7</div>
            <div class="dataNumber">8</div>
            <div class="dataNumber">9</div>
            <div class="dataNumber">4</div>
            <div class="dataNumber">5</div>
            <div class="dataNumber">6</div>
            <div class="dataNumber">1</div>
            <div class="dataNumber">2</div>
            <div class="dataNumber">3</div>
            <div class="dataNumber">.</div>
            <div class="dataNumber">0</div>
            <div class="dataEquals">=</div>
        </div>
        <div id="operators">
            <div class="dataClear">C</div>
            <div class="dataOperator">+</div>
            <div class="dataOperator">-</div>
            <div class="dataOperator">x</div>
            <div class="dataOperator">/</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a delegation version

I also simplified your 0 and dot code

```js
const myInput = document.getElementById('result');
const keys = document.getElementById("keys");
const myOperator = document.getElementById('operator');
const dataEquals = document.querySelector('.dataEquals');
const dataClear = document.querySelector('.dataClear');


let disNum1 = '';
let disNum2 = '';
let result = '';
let hasDot = false;
let hasZero = false;
let lastOperation = '';

keys.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.closest("#numbers")) {
    const clickedNum = tgt.textContent;
    if (clickedNum === '.') {
      if (hasDot) return
      else hasDot = true;
      if (hasZero) return
      else hasZero = true;
    }
    disNum1 += clickedNum;
    myInput.value = disNum1;
    return;
  } 
  if (tgt.closest("#operators")) {
    hasDot = false;
    hasZero = false;
    const clickedOp = tgt.textContent;
    if (clickedOp === "C") {
      myInput.value = "";
      myOperator.value = "";
      disNum1 = disNum2 = '';
      return
    }
    lastOperation = clickedOp;
    myOperator.value = clickedOp;
    disNum2 = disNum1;
    disNum1 = '';
  }
})




function mathOperation() {
  if (lastOperation === 'x') {
    result = parseFloat(disNum2) * parseFloat(disNum1);
  } else if (lastOperation === "+") {
    result = parseFloat(disNum2) + parseFloat(disNum1);
  } else if (lastOperation === "-") {
    result = parseFloat(disNum2) - parseFloat(disNum1);
  } else if (lastOperation === "/") {
    result = parseFloat(disNum2) / parseFloat(disNum1);
  } else if (lastOperation === "%") {
    result = parseFloat(disNum2) % parseFloat(disNum1);
  }
}

dataEquals.addEventListener("click", () => {
  hasDot = false;
  hasZero = false;
  mathOperation();
  myInput.value = result;
  disNum2 = result; // Your result is now also the 2nd number.
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#calculator {
  width: 500px;
}

#keys {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

#numbers {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 75%;
  justify-content: center;
}

#operators {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#numbers div,
#operators div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
}

#numbers div {
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

#numbers div:active,
#operators div:active {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
}

#screen {
  margin: 18px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
  background-color: rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3);
  display: flex;
}

#result,
#operator {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 42px;
  text-align: right;
  border: none;
}

#operator {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <div id="screen">
    <input type="text" id="result" placeholder="0" value="" disabled>
    <input type="text" id="operator" disabled>
  </div>
  <div id="keys">
    <div id="numbers">
      <div class="dataNumber">7</div>
      <div class="dataNumber">8</div>
      <div class="dataNumber">9</div>
      <div class="dataNumber">4</div>
      <div class="dataNumber">5</div>
      <div class="dataNumber">6</div>
      <div class="dataNumber">1</div>
      <div class="dataNumber">2</div>
      <div class="dataNumber">3</div>
      <div class="dataNumber">.</div>
      <div class="dataNumber">0</div>
      <div class="dataEquals">=</div>
    </div>
    <div id="operators">
      <div class="dataClear">C</div>
      <div class="dataOperator">+</div>
      <div class="dataOperator">-</div>
      <div class="dataOperator">x</div>
      <div class="dataOperator">/</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```